# Remove everything after '/?' if occurs

Tags: php

I have the URL `https://instagram.com/p/7XEvAXLTaDvhyAX4DJORqLi7857T-mtP_C8RY0/?taken-by=porcelainstorm`  that I only need `7XEvAXLTaDvhyAX4DJORqLi7857T-mtP_C8RY0` from the URL so that it can become a table name.

But not all the time will the URL contain the trailing `/?taken-by=porcelainstorm`  (or other string)
I am able to remove the initial part of the url using trim

```
$trimmed = trim($_SESSION['URL'], "https://instagram.com/p/");
```

But I am unable to remove the trailing portion

```
$trimmed = substr($variable, 0, strpos($variable, "\/\?"));
```

output of `var_dump($trimmed)`:

```
1069344258914072195_611397892string(55) "7XEvAXLTaDvhyAX4DJORqLi7857T-mtP_C8RY0/?taken-by=porcel"
```

How do I remove the trailing portion of the URL, when it occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about properly parsing the URL with [**`parse_url`**](http://php.net/parse_url) to get the path instead?

```
$path = parse_url($_SESSION['URL'], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Then you can use [**`basename`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to get the last part of the path:

```
$value_you_want = basename($path);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/8vKmAaXj)

Comment: That worked beautifully. PHP has a few caveats that it does really well and that's one of them!